# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table when run 'rake db:migrate:reset'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails version 4.2.5
Ruby version 2.3.1p112

When I run 'rake db:migrate:reset', I get an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error.
The error message says "Could not find table 'pass_codes'".

This error is in the **!exists?(code: code)** line.

Shouldn't it be a class method?
Please let me know if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

```
class PassCode < ActiveRecord::Base
# Some parts are omitted.

  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :code, with: /\A\d{8}\z/

  def self.generate_unique_code
    100.times do
      generated_code = sprintf(
        "%012d" % SecureRandom.random_number(1_0000_0000)
      )
      if code_unique?(generated_code)
        return generated_code
      end
    end
  end

  def self.code_unique
  def self.code_unique?(code)
    !exists?(code: code)
  end

end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :pass_code do
    code PassCode.generate_unique_code
  end
end
```

full stack trace

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'pass_codes'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:511:in `table_structure'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:385:in `columns'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:969:in `block in create_binds'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:967:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:967:in `partition'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:967:in `create_binds'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:954:in `build_where'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:584:in `where!'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:574:in `where'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:295:in `exists?'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `exists?'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/app/models/pass_code.rb:61:in `code_unique?'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/app/models/pass_code.rb:54:in `block in generate_unique_code'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/app/models/pass_code.rb:50:in `times'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/app/models/pass_code.rb:50:in `generate_unique_code'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/spec/factories/pass_codes.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/spec/factories/pass_codes.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/spec/factories/pass_codes.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.6.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atmoph/chamonix/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/oyuka/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
./bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
'''
```

Comment: Please post the full backtrace. This model you've posted does not invoke the `.code_unique?` method. Do you have a migration that creates the `pass_codes` table?

Comment: Sean Huber Thank you for your cooperation. I've posted the full backtrace. And I've added the code that I omitted. By the way, I realized my mistake: In FactoryGirl, I used `.generate_unique_code?`. `.generate_unique_code` is using `.code_unique?`. Changing the fixed value does not abort rake. Thanks to your response, I noticed this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be invoking any FactoryGirl code when running `rake db:migrate`. Other people have had similar issues years ago, but since you on an older version of rails and factory_girl you are likely running into these older issues. If you google "rails db:migrate factory_girl" you'll find several examples. Here is one with some good discussion:

https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1218283

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I removed the factory_girl and the error went away. Thanks for letting me know about the discussion as well. I'll take a look.

Comment: No problem and happy to help. Cheers!